# From database into JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

My code show data from database into table correctly
But when i want to delete a row, Row is delete from database and table model,

But a `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1` exception occur:

```
public class Model1 extends DefaultTableModel {

public Model1(Vector<Vector<String>> data, Vector<String> column) {
    super(data, column);
}

public void removeRow(int rowToModel, Object rowId) {
    JDBC1 jdbc1 = new JDBC1();

    try {
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);

        ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from table where id=?");
        ps.setObject(1, rowId);

        if (ps.executeUpdate() == 1) {
            jdbc1.getColumns().remove(rowToModel);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(rowToModel, rowToModel);
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My JDBC Class:

```
public class JDBC1 {

private Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>();
Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection con;
Statement statement;
ResultSet result;
String query = "Select * from table";

public Vector<String> getColumn() throws SQLException {

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    statement = con.createStatement();
    result = statement.executeQuery(query);

    int c = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
        getColumns().add(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
    }
    return getColumns();
}

public Vector<Vector<String>> getData() throws SQLException{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    statement = con.createStatement();
    result = statement.executeQuery(query);
    int c = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

    while (result.next()) {
        Vector<String> newRow = new Vector<String>(c);

        for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            newRow.add(result.getString(i));
        }
        data.add(newRow);
    }
    return data;

}

public Vector<String> getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setColumns(Vector<String> columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}
}
```

GUI Class:

```
public class GUI1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTable table;
Model1 model1;
JDBC1 jdbc1;
JButton dellButton;

public GUI1() {
    try {
        jdbc1 = new JDBC1();
        model1 = new Model1(jdbc1.getData(), jdbc1.getColumn());
        table = new JTable(model1);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(dellButton() , BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(600, 550);
    setLocation(250, 85);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI1();
}

public JPanel dellButton(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    dellButton = new JButton("Delete Row");
    dellButton.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(dellButton);
    return panel;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == dellButton) {
        dellAction();
    }
}

public void dellAction() {
    if (table.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
        int rowToDelete = table.getSelectedRow();
        int rowToModel = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowToDelete);
        Object rowId = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
        model1.removeRow(rowToModel, rowId);

    } else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select Row");
}
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1
at java.util.Vector.remove(Vector.java:827)
at test.Model1.removeRow(Model1.java:29)
at test.GUI1.dellAction(GUI1.java:76)
at test.GUI1.actionPerformed(GUI1.java:67)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: I've lost track of how many times this (and related) questions have been asked by this person because this is the 3rd userid this person is using. The most recent question is (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18580515/131872) where the OP has been given plenty of advice. You can also follow other questions on this topic using his other userid (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1900445/sajjad). I find this game of changing userids childish and sure hope this does not get the OP future answers until he starts listening to suggestions that have already been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your seem to mixing your column information with your data.

The columns describe, well, the columns, that appear horizontally across the table, where the rows describe the actually data (structured to fit into the columns)...

Instead of...

```
jdbc1.getColumns().remove(rowToModel);
```

Try...

```
removeRow(rowToModel);
```

This will relieve you of the need to call `fireTableRowsDeleted` yourself...

**Observation**

Personally, I would try a limit the amount of information that the `dellAction` method needs in order to delete a row.

What I mean is, the method already knows the row to be deleted, it should not have to lookup the ID as well.  This suggests that the `dellAction` method knows something about the structure of the view, which may change in the future.

Instead, personally, I would extract the ID from the row data within in the `removeRow` method itself.  This allows the model the opportunity to model the ID or not, based on your needs...

IMHO

Comment: `What I mean is, the method already knows the row to be deleted, it should have the need to lookup the ID as well` - already suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18617834/131872

Comment: @camickr May be if enough people suggest it, the OP will listen, or we could keep banging the brick wall on them ;)

Comment: Multiple people should not have to make the suggestion in order for the OP to listen. The OP has been wasting peoples time for almost a month on related questions :( His solution here is getting even worse and I don't see how your suggestion will help. The OP is trying to keep the JTable and database table in sync. The getData() method will query the database and create a Vector of data. The code then delete a row from the Vector. This has no effect on the data in the TableModel or the JTable.

Comment: @camickr Some people just don't want to hear that they're ideas aren't the best.  Shame we don't have a "waste of time" option for closing questions.  Also, thanks.  I was on the iPad while watching Peppa Pig with my daughter when I was reading the question, missed the `getData` methods functionality....:P

Comment: Well, Where should use `removeRow(rowToModel);` ? in `gui1` Class or in `Model1` Class?

Comment: Both if required, but the model is ultimately responsible for removing the row from within its cache